# TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list (list comprehension)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list-comprehension, typeerror

I'm trying to check if the words in the list show up in my column if words show up in the column, then convert to 1 else 0. but Im getting `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list` error.

```
top_words_list = ['great', 'love', 'good',
                  'story', 'loved', 'excellent',
                  'series', 'best', 'one']
[1 if re.search(top_words_list) in i else 0 for i in amazon['reviewer_summary']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for

```
[1 if any(word in i for word in top_words_list) else 0 for i in amazon['reviewer_summary']]
```

`re.search()` returns a `list` of all the matches. So, when you do `if re.search() in i`, you are checking `if <list> in <string>` which is why it's raising `TypeError`.

A small demonstration for the same:

```
>>> chars_to_check = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> sentence = 'this is a sentence'
>>> chars_to_check in sentence
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
>>>
>>> any(c in sentence for c in chars_to_check)
True
```